# Javascript Form Submit with Email Action?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need make this form send me a email like a contact form:

Script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#contactLink").click(function(){
                if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
                    $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
                }
                else{
                    $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
                }
            });

        });

        function closeForm(){
            $("#messageSent").show("slow");
            setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
       }
       </script>
```

HTML CODE:

```
   <div class="box">
        <div id="contactFormContainer">
            <div id="contactForm">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="Name">Nome: </label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" />
                    <label for="Telefone">Telefone Fixo: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone" maxlength="15" onkeypress="Mascara(this);" />
                    <label for="Message">Assunto:</label>
                    <textarea id="Message" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
                    <input id="sendMail" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="closeForm()" />           
                    <span id="messageSent">Sua solicitação foi enviada com sucesso, por favor, aguarde...</span>
               </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div id="contactLink"></div>
        </div>
```

When click and close the form i need send me a email with the content of form, how to?
Some idea? thanks!

Comment: does your closeForm() function works, it looks a little bit weird for me.

Comment: you need some kind of backend solution to send an email 100% reliable, i.e. some Ruby/PHP/Node.JS/Script which sends the email. There is a construction with "mailto:" in HTML, but this is neither professional nor does it always work.

Comment: Yes Vdt, works perfectly but i just don't know how to add a function to email me when the closeForm() function is activated. Sometime ago i saw something like a fuction to call a page, this probably can solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly i can't see the form tags in your code. According to me you're doing this wrong and i'm sure many of our friends on stack will agree too.

Your question suggests that you basically want to receive an email with the data submitted through the form. Why don't you try the below method.

**HTML**

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">

 <input type="text" name="fname"></input>

 <input type="text" name="lname"></input>

 <button>SUBMIT</button>

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];

$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Hello World";
$message = "Firstname: $firstname \n\n Lastname: $lastname";
$from = "sender@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

The above example is the most simplest method of sending an email. You can go advance by adding more header information and graphically formatting the email.

Go through these tutorials if you get confused.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/8.html

And since you mentioned that you want to perform the task via javascript you can try submitting the form via ajax, refer the below tutorials

http://teachingyou.net/php/simple-php-contact-form-using-ajax/

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1055068-Send-PHP-email-using-jQuery-AJAX

Comment: Close, but when i put a html form action I lose my jquery effect and a new window open or just go to other page. Have some way to call a invisible page with javascript?

Comment: Thanks Dalton, your ajax tutorial solved my problem. - Obrigado!

Comment: Agreed, form action will kill your jquery effect. To avoid this you will need to submit the data asynchronously and you can do this via ajax. You can set the ajax to return false, this will prevent the page refresh or redirect. for your jquery animations, you can simply add them inside your ajax success/after/before/complete handlers based on your requirement. refer the ajax tutorial. and here is an example of what i've done for a client www.privyshoppr.com/get-listed.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged the question php, have a look at php's mail function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$to = 'you@domain.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form';
$message = '...' //concatenate the $_POST (or $_GET) variables to create this message

mail($to, $subject, wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
```

This function requires that your server has a properly configured to send mail - see the php documentation for requirements: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php